Difficulty Managing Manager Chain in Employee Catalog Implementation
I'm developing an Employee Catalog using Java Spring Boot, and I'm encountering difficulties managing the manager chain within my Here are the details of my project:

Each employee record should include information of his department and his manager. Manager's manager should be usually null. Unless it's requested to get full chain of managers.

Here's the code implementation I wrote and domain classes:
@Repository
public class EmployeeRepositoryImpl implements EmployeeRepository{

private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Autowired
public EmployeeRepositoryImpl(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
}
    @Autowired
    public EmployeeRepositoryImpl(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

@Override
public List<Employee> findAll(int page, int size, String sort) {
    String query = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE ORDER BY " + sort;
    List<Employee> employees = jdbcTemplate.query(query, new EmployeeRowMapper(jdbcTemplate));
    return getList(employees, page, size);
}

@Override
public Optional<Employee> findById(Long id, boolean fullChain) {
    String query = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE ID = ?";
    Employee employee = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query, new Object[]{id}, new EmployeeRowMapper(jdbcTemplate));
    return Optional.ofNullable(employee);
}


@Override
public List<Employee> findEmployeesByManager(Long managerId, int page, int size, String sort) {
    String query = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE MANAGER = ? ORDER BY " + sort;
    List<Employee> employees = jdbcTemplate.query(query, new Object[]{managerId}, new EmployeeRowMapper(jdbcTemplate));
    return getList(employees, page, size);
}


@Override
public List<Employee> findEmployeesByDepartmentId(Long departmentId, int page, int size, String sort) {
    String query = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE DEPARTMENT = ? ORDER BY " + sort;
    List<Employee> employees = jdbcTemplate.query(query, new Object[]{departmentId}, new EmployeeRowMapper(jdbcTemplate));
    return getList(employees, page, size);
}
private List<Employee> getList(List<Employee> employees, int page, int size) {
    int startIndex = page * size;
    int endIndex = Math.min(startIndex + size, employees.size());
    return employees.subList(startIndex, endIndex);
}

private static class EmployeeRowMapper implements RowMapper<Employee> {
    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    private EmployeeRowMapper(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    private static List<Long> employeeManager = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public Employee mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException {
        Long id = resultSet.getLong("ID");
        String firstName = resultSet.getString("FIRSTNAME");
        String lastName = resultSet.getString("LASTNAME");
        String middleName = resultSet.getString("MIDDLENAME");
        FullName fullName = new FullName(firstName, lastName, middleName);
        Position position = Position.valueOf(resultSet.getString("POSITION"));
        LocalDate hired = resultSet.getDate("HIREDATE").toLocalDate();
        BigDecimal salary = BigDecimal.valueOf(resultSet.getDouble("SALARY"));
        Long managerId = resultSet.getLong("MANAGER");
        Employee manager = null;
        if (employeeManager.isEmpty()) {
            manager = findEmployee(managerId);
        }
        Long departmentId = resultSet.getLong("DEPARTMENT");
        Department department = findDepartment(departmentId);
        Employee employee = new Employee(id, fullName, position, hired, salary, manager, department);
        return employee;
    }

    private Department findDepartment(Long departmentId) {
        if (departmentId == 0) return null;
        String query = "SELECT * FROM DEPARTMENT WHERE ID = ?";
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query, new Object[]{departmentId}, new DepartmentRowMapper());
    }

    private Employee findEmployee(Long managerId) {
        if (managerId == 0) return null;
        employeeManager.add(managerId);
        String query = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE ID = ?";
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query, new Object[]{managerId}, new EmployeeRowMapper(jdbcTemplate));
    }

    private static class DepartmentRowMapper implements RowMapper<Department> {

        @Override
        public Department mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException {
            Long id = resultSet.getLong("ID");
            String name = resultSet.getString("NAME");
            String location = resultSet.getString("LOCATION");
            return new Department(id, name, location);
        }
    }

}
}

I've attempted to address this by creating separate methods (findFullManagerChain and findImmediateManager) and passing the fullChain parameter to the RowMapper. However, I'm unsure how to integrate this properly.
Could someone please provide guidance on how to split the findEmployee method in the RowMapper into two, and how to connect the findById method to the RowMapper to fetch the appropriate manager chain based on the fullChain parameter?
